# Regex parse with alteryx

Tags: regex, alteryx

One of the columns has the data as below and I only need the suburb name, not the state or postcode.

I'm using Alteryx and tried regex `(\<\w+\>)\s\<\w+\>` but only get a few records to the new column.

Input:

```
CABRAMATTA          
CANLEY HEIGHTS      
ST JOHNS PARK       
Parramatta NSW 2150 
Claymore 2559       
CASULA
```

Output

```
CABRAMATTA          
CANLEY HEIGHTS      
ST JOHNS PARK       
Parramatta
Claymore
CASULA
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: I'm trying to use alteryx to trim off the state and postal. Please look carefully at the input and outpout records. For Parramatta I need to remove NSW and 2150.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It's just that you forgot to define "state" and "postal" in precise (i.e. technical) terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex matches all letter-words up to but not including an Australian state abbreviation (since the addresses are clearly Australian):

```
( ?(?!(VIC|NSW|QLD|TAS|SA|WA|ACT|NT)\b)\b[a-zA-Z]+)+
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/Ma7aTAXwKJ)

The negative look ahead includes a word boundary to allow suburbs that start with a state abbreviation (see demo).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Bohemian's answer, you can use groupings to do a REGEXP REPLACE in alteryx. So:

```
REGEX_Replace([Field1], "(.*)(\VIC|NSW|QLD|TAS|SA|WA|ACT|NT)+(\s*\d+)" , "\1")
```

This will grab anything that matches in the first group (so just the suburb). The second and third groups match the state and the zip. Not a perfect regex, but should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this workflow will help you :

[image]